# Tumblr links showing up on blog's theme even when they should be off

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I recently (maybe about 3-4 days ago) saw that my tumblr blog now contains floating buttons (or a box in mobile) with tumblr promoting their website/app. The thing is, you can change this setting in your theme settings. But it still is in the off position and the links do not go away.

[image: example of links in blog (desktop, top of page)]

I tried turning it on and off and keeping it on any position for more than a day and every time it gives the same result - the links are still being shown.

I don't know if this has anything to do with it (I'm fresh out of ideas), but my blog is a secondary blog, is over two years old, has 10k+ followers and I flagged it as an adult-orientated (the content is slightly suggestive and would probably be not fit for children). My so called primary blog (that I don't actually use) has the same settings yet the links do not show.

As you can see from the small image above, those buttons overlap the design and in the mobile version it attracts too much attention. That's why I want to remove them.

**Edit:**

It is possible to hide those buttons with CSS on desktop

```
.tmblr-iframe {
    display: none;
}
```

But on smartphones while the banner is hidden, it still occupies space as there's probably a javascript code that adds that space on load.

While this might be better than nothing, it's still not the correct way (and the worst part is that it still generates an empty space on smartphones).

I forgot to mention this, but doing a hard refresh or clearing your cache completely didn't help me though I know someone who's cache was the problem. In my situation, four different devices would produce the same bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was all on the tumblr's technical side of things. It was neither my custom theme nor the settings that were affecting this. Contacting the tumblr's support fixed my issue (I didn't receive a response from tumblr's support about the success of fixing the issue, but after submitting my issue and one reply later, it seems to be fixed).

If any of you have the same issue, I guess the only way is to contact the tumblr's support as there is nothing you can do about it on your end.